# Delphi Soap Server Interface dynamic loader

Tags: delphi, soap, dll, interface

Its possible to make an delphi soap server application to load an 3rd party soap server interface?

If the answer is YES, could share a piece of code for example?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done some research? Share some links atleast

Comment: I dont find anything like this in google or bing! I'm trying to load a soap webservice in delphi in application start off the IIS server.

Comment: Do you mean so that the Delphi app would be a kind of local proxy  for the 3rd party one?

Comment: @MartynA Yes, but i'm trying to do is to put something here for dynamic load a soap server interface hosted in a dll:  library XXX
exports
  GetExtensionVersion,
  HttpExtensionProc,
  TerminateExtension;

begin
  CoInitFlags := COINIT_MULTITHREADED;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TWebModule1, WebModule1); 

  code for load dll with the soap server interface

  Application.Run;
end.